# Изменить цвет текста в строке датафрейма по условию

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть датафрейм df_df1

[image: df_df1]

Мне нужно изменить цвет текста в тех строках (полностью всю строку), в которых значения ячеек по столбцу/ам column5 и/или column6 удовлетворяют условиям x < 0 и x >= 100.

Я использую следующий код:

`df_df1.style.map(lambda x: (x<0 and "color: grey") or "color: black")`

На выходе получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы можете заметить, я использовал пока только одно условие x < 0. Такие значения есть в column5 и/или column6 в строке с индексом 3. Но я хочу, чтобы в таком случае изменился цвет всей строки (а тут значения в column2 и column4 остались черными).

Теперь добавлю в код второе условие x >= 100:

`df_df1.style.map(lambda x: (x<0 and "color: grey") or (x>100 and "color: grey") or "color: black")`

На выходе получу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня закрасились все подходящие значения, хотя мне надо, чтобы серыми стали строки с индексом 3 и 6, потому что в этих строках в столбцах column5 и column6 есть значения, удовлетворяющие нужным условиям

Помогите, пожалуйста, подсказками, что можно сделать, чтобы получить желаемый результат на выходе

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 150, 100).reshape(10, -1)).add_prefix('column', axis=1)
df_style = df.style.apply(lambda x: ["color: black"] * len(x) if 0 <= x.column5 < 100 and 0 <= x.column6 < 100 else ["color: grey"] * len(x), axis=1)
df_style.to_excel('styler.xlsx')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дополнение**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 150, 100).reshape(10, -1)).add_prefix('column', axis=1)
df['column1'] = df['column1'].mul(1.11111).round(2)
df['column2'] = df['column2'].mul(3.3333).map('{:,.2%}'.format) # в колонке 2 делаем проценты с 2 десятичными знаками

df_style = df.style.apply(lambda x: ["color: black"] * len(x) if 0 <= x.column5 < 100 and 0 <= x.column6 < 100 else ["color: grey"] * len(x), axis=1)
df_style = df_style.set_properties(**{"text-align": "right"}, subset=['column2']) # выравниваем колонку 2 с процентами по правому краю
df.style.data['column7'] = 'можно поменять данные после форматирования'
df_style.to_excel('styler.xlsx')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, получилось. но я хочу после форматирования дальше работать с датафреймом, а мне выдает ошибку ````'Styler' object is not subscriptable````. например, я хочу добавить знаки процента в некоторые столбцы, некоторые столбцы округлить до 1 знака запятой или сделать int. использование метода .data отменяет сделанное форматирование(

Comment: Сначала работаете с данными, форматируете в конце

Comment: спасибо. но мне надо df.style.data['column7'] приравнять к df['column2'], а потом некоторые столбцы просто удалить, но styler object этого не позволяет сделать

Comment: Точнее, мне надо сначала из колонок column5 и column6 сделать проценты и потом по этим же колонкам перекрасить цвета строк. Но когда прописываю в lambda функции условие со знаком процента или просто десятичное число, то код не срабатывает, так как не понимает что в колонке (а там уже строка, а не числа). Поэтому я думал создать дублирующие столбцы, а после форматирования отобразить только нужные, но так не получается